# How to call cmd batch from within powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have

C:\folder\tail.exe

C:\logs\logfile.log

C:\script\shellscript.ps1

How do I run the C:\folder\tail.exe from within the C:\script\shellscript.ps1

I need to run "C:\folder\tailf.exe C:\logs\logfile.log" from within C:\script\shellscript.ps1 but without relying a seperate batch file, i need to call it directly.

Normally I do: cd C:\folder\ and then tailf.exe C:\logs\logfile.log

Inside C:\script\shellscript.ps1 I tried

```
start-process C:\fetchmail\tail.exe -argumentlist "C:\fetchmail\logs\fetchmail.log"
```

i can see a window flashing but dont know if it works, the window should stay open.

Answer (score 7):

You can do what you normally do:

```
C:\folder\tail.exe c:\logs\logfile.log
```

Note that if the paths have spaces in them you have to do:

```
& "C:\fol der\tail.exe" "c:\log s\logfile.log"
```

Answer (score 3):

1. To accomplish tail.exe running in a **separate window** and **not having the window closed immediately**, try:

   `cmd /k c:\folder\tail.exe c:\logs\test.log`
2. To start tail.exe in the powershell window, try:

   `C:\folder\tail.exe c:\logs\logfile.log`
3. Assuming `tail.exe` is **Tail for Win32**, this is a powershell equivalent of your command:

   `get-content c:\logs\logfile.log | select -last 10`
4. In the [Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) there is a **Get-FileTail** cmdlet which is a more efficient native powershell tail equivalent.

Comment: You can just type `cmd /k c:\folder\tail.exe c:\logs\test.log` in PowerShell. It's a *shell* after all. There are some idiosyncrasies with arguments to programs but they don't apply here